# How to get uncommon elements between arrays in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following piece of HAML code:

```
  %li  
  %label 
    #{t('Registrations.new.CheckBoxHeader')}
    %abbr.required{title: t('Registrations.new.Required')} *
- if !current_user.roles.blank? 
 - current_user.roles.each do |roles|
   - (roles[:name] & Role::ROLES).each do |role| 
   %input#roles{name: "access[]", type: "checkbox",value:"#{role}"}/
   %label{for: "roles"} #{role}
- else
 - Role::ROLES.each do |role| 
   %input#roles{name: "access[]", type: "checkbox",value:"#{role}"}/
   %label{for: "roles"} #{role}
```

I want to display only those roles in the checkbox that are not common between `roles[:name]` and `Role::ROLES`.

I know I am doing something wrong here. I know `&` in Ruby gives intersection, but that seems not to be working either.

Comment: what are the values of roles and Role::ROLES

Answer (score 0):

do this `

```
unless Role::ROLES.include?(roles[:name])`
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's get all that logic and data coupling out of your view. Also, you need the union operator, not the intersection one.

In your controller:

```
@roles = current_user.roles.pluck(:name) | Role::ROLES
```

That will make your view a lot cleaner:

```
   %li  
     %label 
       #{t('Registrations.new.CheckBoxHeader')}
       %abbr.required{title: t('Registrations.new.Required')} *
 - @roles.each do |role|
   %input#roles{name: "access[]", type: "checkbox",value:"#{role}"}/
   %label{for: "roles"} #{role}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but | doesn't seem to work but & gives me the common values .

Comment: Yes, `&` will give you the common values. But in your question you asked for the **not** common values. Anyway, just switch operators and see how it goes.